# modal-backdrop bootstrap class creating problems

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootbox

In an ASP.NET MVC5 application i get the issue of getting the modal backdrop in front of a dialog box from bootbox.

This happens ONLY in chrome and not in firefox.

I ichecked and read various SO posts and i checked their proposals that i dont have unclosed divs or anything else.

for the time being the only way i found to correct this is putting `z-index: -1` to `.modal-backdrop`

Is this the proposed solution?

and why firefox is ok?